# Flash Builder 4.7 on MacOSX suddenly won't build anymore

Tags: macos, flash-builder

I was developing an Actionscript application with Flash Builder and all of the sudden it just stopped building.
I check on and off automatic build, clean everything, force build all, and the SWF file just remains untouched.
I did nothing in the middle, I was fixing bugs, then debugging and seeing the code changes reflected in the SWF file. But suddenly it just runs the same SWF over and over ignoring the changes I make to the code.
When I force it to build all, it copies some files from the src folder, but the SWF is not affected ever.
It has no build errors.
I also checked on and off the generation of a wrapper HTML, but it doesn't do it, it just complains when trying to run it that the html is not there.

I've read some workarounds like changing the AIR SDK used, to force FB to rebuild, but doesn't work either.

I'm using Flash Builder 4.7 on Mac OSX, with AIR SDK 3.4

Comment: Have you tried manually deleting the SWF before rebuilding?

Comment: @Brian Yes, I delete it, when I try to build it just does nothing, then when I try to debug it, FB complains that it can't find the SWF, no kidding.

Comment: Sounds like you have build errors that are stopping the compilation process.

Comment: Nope, there are no build errors, at least none reported by FB. And the same code was compiling moments before.

Comment: Hmm.  That IS strange.  Try checking out the code into a new workspace?